# Can't automatically import Stylus file to VueJS project

Tags: vue.js, webpack, stylus, stylus-loader

For the past 2 days, I've been trying to figure out how to import a global stylus file into all of my components so that I don't end up with `@import '../../../styles.styl' in each component or ever need to adjust that. I've used the configuration given by VueJS [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#automatic-imports) and I still can't figure it out. I've tried various different configurations, but every time it either doesn't recognize 'style-resources-loader' and gives me an error before even building, or it seems to build and then errors out because it doesn't recognize the stylus variables I'm using in my components. Giving me this error:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/stylus-loader/index.js):
Error: C:\filepath\ViewTitle.vue:27:25
   23|     color white
   24|     font-family 'Xiomara'
   25|     letter-spacing 0.25rem
   26|     text-align center
   27|     text-shadow 0 0 8px rgba(light, 0.1)
-------------------------------^
   28| </style>

TypeError: expected rgba or hsla, but got function:light(color)
```

I've also tried the `css: { loaderOptions: { stylus: prependData: "@import './assets/styles/styles.styl'" } } }` and that has not worked either. Any thoughts?

Edit:
This is what my variables look like:

```
peppermint = #FBAAA6
dusk = #135A8B
gold = #F0D355
dark = #062236
light = #EFF2F3
```

I have them stored in `./assets/styles/config/vars.styl`, then the file I'm trying to import is in `./assets/styles/styles.styl` and that file imports the `vars.styl`

Solution:
For anyone having the same issue, I ended up just starting over. Luckily I wasn't too deep into the project, so it only set me back a few hours. Using the code in the Auto Import section of the VueJS documentation worked fine after starting fresh.

Comment: show how the light variable is defined

Comment: you can compare with example on the stylus site: https://stylus-lang.com/try.html#?code=light%20%3D%20black%0Abody%20%7B%0A%20%20font%3A%2014px%2F1.5%20Helvetica%2C%20arial%2C%20sans-serif%3B%0A%20%20%23logo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20border-radius%3A%205px%3B%0A%20%20%20%20border-color%3A%20rgba(light%2C%200.5)%0A%20%20%20%20text-shadow%200%200%208px%20rgba(light%2C%200.1)%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D

Comment: @Anatoly Updated with the definition! It looks to be right with the site, I haven't had issues before and the issue disappears when I include it in each individual component, so I don't think there are any issues there,